# Continuous Runtime Error

Tags: c++

Can please anybody help me why my code is giving runtime error: I am
not able to find any error.

The programs aims to find the prime using sieve plus find the smallest prime factor for every number n

where n is in the range 1<=n<=10^7

```
#include<iostream>
#include<vector>
#include<cmath>
#include<cstdio>
#include<cstring>
typedef long long ll;
#define MAX 10000000

using namespace std;



bool arr[MAX+1]={false};
int sp[MAX+1]={0};





void Sieve(){
for (int i = 2; i <= MAX; i=i+2)    
{sp[i] = 2;
}
for (int i = 3; i <= MAX; i=i+2)
{
    if (arr[i]==false)
    {
        sp[i] = i;

        for (int j = i; (j*i) <= MAX; j=j+2)
        {
            if (arr[j*i]==false)
            {

                arr[j*i] = true;
                sp[j*i] = i;

            }
        }
    }
}
}




//inline int scan_d()    {int ip=getchar_unlocked(),ret=0,flag=1;for(;ip<'0'||ip>'9';ip=getchar_unlocked())if(ip=='-'){flag=-1;ip=getchar_unlocked();break;}for(;ip>='0'&&ip<='9';ip=getchar_unlocked())ret=ret*10+ip-'0';return flag*ret;}


int main()
{


Sieve();

return 0;    

}
```

Comment: Have you tried using a debugger? It should help you find where it crashes

Comment: Actually i'm compiling it on an ide and it's showing runtime error.

Comment: Compiling doesn't show runtime errors. What errors are you getting?

Comment: I'm not using any debugger..I'm just running it on ideone.com and it's showing RUNTIME ERROR

Comment: Then run it through a debugger. We can't help unless you tell us what the problem is

Answer (score 2):

for a large enough `i` (here I get error when `i=46349`), the inner looping cause the error: `j` is initialized with `i`(=46349), and then the condition `(j*i) <= MAX` behave unexpected due to an overflow and `j*i` gave a negative result.
One way to solve this is restrict the range of `i` (which also enhances the performance):

```
int sqrtMAX=sqrt(MAX);
// write it globally or somewhere before the looping.
// thanks to @Thomas Matthews
...
for (int i = 3; i <= sqrtMAX/*instead of MAX*/ ; i=i+2)
    if (arr[i]==false)
        {
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot mahn
I got it
I changed both i and j to long long
Thanks.. Cheers

Comment: @shooter_buster Another help vampire served. How do you actually think your question will be useful for future research? Elaborate please.

Comment: Calculating the `sqrt(MAX)` into a constant variable before the `for` loop may speed up the program.

Comment: @ThomasMatthews Thanks. I just wrote it too quickly without thinking. I am wondering whether the compiler can optimize it if I write `sqrt` in `for` ?

Comment: Depends on the compiler optimization levels.  First compile with no optimizations and print assembly listing.  Next, set optimization level higher (or highest) and print assembly listing.  Compare the two assembly language listings.  The Truth is in the assembly language.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ  Please can u write your name in translated form..
I think your name needs a bit of research :P :P :P

Comment: @shooter_buster Nothing that cannot be found from my profile page: See https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Panta_Rhei